# Laravel Eloquent: Append queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to "append" queries in `Laravel`?

For example like so in this example code:

```
function crunchNumbersForToday()
{
    return $this->crunchSomeInformationInRange(Payments::where('created_at', Carbon::now()));
}

function crunchNumbersInRange($range)
{
    $paymentsToCrunch = Payment::where('state', 'payed')->append($range)->get();

    // Work with the payments
}
```

So in this case the `where` of the `created_at` field would be appended to the query where `state` equals `payed`. Which would make something like: `where created_at = '2015-07-08 12:00' AND state = payed`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could create a [`scope`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes).

For your code that would be (in your `Payment` model):

```
function scopeToday($query)
{
    return $query->where('created_at', Carbon::now());
}

function scopeNumbersInRange($query)
{
    return $query->where('state', 'payed');

    // Work with the payments
}
```

And then call it elsewhere in your code like:

```
Payment::numbersInRange()->today()->get();
```

Edit:
You can make them dynamic too:

```
function scopeDate($query, $date)
{
    return $query->where('created_at', $date);
}
```

...

```
Payment::numersInRange()->date(Carbon::now())->get();
```

And so on. This way you can keep chaining scopes.

Comment: Not exactly like "passing query parts around". But it's suitable for my problem.

Comment: This way you (optionally) add query parts to the QueryBuilder. You can chain as many as you want and build the query that way, you can make them dynamic too, of course. Next to $query you can pass along more variables that you can use in your query. (whether that's a ->where() or something else)

Comment: I could now ofcourse do something like this: function doSomething($scopeName) { Payment::$scopeName('param')->get(); } So, it's getting close.